# How do I stretch a texture to fill a 2d polygon in Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

I've seen a lot about texture.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat,....), but that is not exactly what I'm after atm. I'm using Rube and Libgdx, with Tescott's rube loader.
Ideally I'd like to use an image like below with the sharp dark line at the top for the ground the car comes into contact with. Has anyone got any resources or tips to point me in the right direction? I believe I will need UV mapping, but where exactly I use this I'm not sure.Thanks.

EDIT: I've also seen Clamp_to_Edge, but I don't think I need this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yIM1.png

```
 Array<Body> bodies = scene.getBodies();

  EarClippingTriangulator ect = new EarClippingTriangulator();

  if ((bodies != null) && (bodies.size > 0))
  {
     mPolySpatials = new Array<PolySpatial>();
     Vector2 bodyPos = new Vector2();
     // for each body in the scene...
     for (int i = 0; i < bodies.size; i++)
     {
        Body body = bodies.get(i);
        bodyPos.set(body.getPosition());

        float bodyAngle = body.getAngle()*MathUtils.radiansToDegrees;

        Array<Fixture> fixtures = body.getFixtureList();

        if ((fixtures != null) && (fixtures.size > 0))
        {
           // for each fixture on the body...
           for (int j = 0; j < fixtures.size; j++)
           {
              Fixture fixture = fixtures.get(j);

              String textureName = (String)scene.getCustom(fixture, "TextureMask", null);
              if (textureName != null)
              {
                 String textureFileName = "data/" + textureName;
                 Texture texture = mTextureMap.get(textureFileName);
                 TextureRegion textureRegion = null;
                 if (texture == null)
                 {
                    texture = new Texture(textureFileName);
                    texture.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat);
                    mTextureMap.put(textureFileName, texture);
                    textureRegion = new TextureRegion(texture);
                    mTextureRegionMap.put(texture, textureRegion);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    textureRegion = mTextureRegionMap.get(texture);
                 }

                 // only handle polygons at this point -- no chain, edge, or circle fixtures.
                 if (fixture.getType() == Shape.Type.Polygon)
                 {
                    PolygonShape shape = (PolygonShape) fixture.getShape();
                    int vertexCount = shape.getVertexCount();
                    float[] vertices = new float[vertexCount * 2];

                    // static bodies are texture aligned and do not get drawn based off of the related body.
                    if (body.getType() == BodyType.StaticBody)
                    {
                       for (int k = 0; k < vertexCount; k++)
                       {

                          shape.getVertex(k, mTmp);
                          mTmp.rotate(bodyAngle);
                          mTmp.add(bodyPos); // convert local coordinates to world coordinates to that textures are
                                             // aligned
                          vertices[k * 2] = mTmp.x * PolySpatial.PIXELS_PER_METER;
                          vertices[k * 2 + 1] = mTmp.y * PolySpatial.PIXELS_PER_METER;
                       }

                       short [] triangleIndices = ect.computeTriangles(vertices).toArray();
                       PolygonRegion region = new PolygonRegion(textureRegion, vertices, triangleIndices);
                       PolySpatial spatial = new PolySpatial(region, Color.WHITE);
                       mPolySpatials.add(spatial);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       // all other fixtures are aligned based on their associated body.
                       for (int k = 0; k < vertexCount; k++)
                       {
                          shape.getVertex(k, mTmp);
                          vertices[k * 2] = mTmp.x * PolySpatial.PIXELS_PER_METER;
                          vertices[k * 2 + 1] = mTmp.y * PolySpatial.PIXELS_PER_METER;
                       }
                       short [] triangleIndices = ect.computeTriangles(vertices).toArray();
                       PolygonRegion region = new PolygonRegion(textureRegion, vertices, triangleIndices);
                       PolySpatial spatial = new PolySpatial(region, body, Color.WHITE);
                       mPolySpatials.add(spatial);
                    }
                 }
```